# htaccess mobile redirect for specific url

Tags: html, .htaccess, mobile

I have a created a duplicate m.website.com that have mobile friendly contents in them. However there are still some desktop page that I did not create a mobile version for it and I don't wish to redirect them to the mobile.

Is there a htaccess code which allows me to redirect just the pages that I wanted to the same url on the mobile site based on the user agent of their device and yet pages that does not have the mobile version created stays in the desktop version? I also want them to be able to choose if they want to go back to the desktop version if they want it to with the links that go back to the desktop page.

www.website.com/page1.htm to m.website.com/page1.htm and www.website.com/page2.htm stay in desktop version if there no mobile version of it.

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Show your current redirection logic. What have you tried to do to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} "text\/vnd\.wap\.wml|application\/vnd\.wap\.xhtml\+xml" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "sony|symbian|nokia|samsung|mobile|windows ce|epoc|opera" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "mini|nitro|j2me|midp-|cldc-|netfront|mot|up\.browser|up\.link|audiovox"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "blackberry|ericsson,|panasonic|philips|sanyo|sharp|sie-"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "portalmmm|blazer|avantgo|danger|palm|series60|palmsource|pocketpc"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "smartphone|rover|ipaq|au-mic,|alcatel|ericy|vodafone\/|wap1\.|wap2\.|iPhone|android"[NC]
RewriteRule ^page1\.htm$ http://m.website.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it like this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/contact\.php$ /contact-mobile.php
```

Just set up a redirect for each specific page you want redirected to a mobile version.

Comment: Thanks for the help. but I guess I didn't stay it clearly in my question. I only want to redirect the mobile user to the mobile site, the desktop user still view the desktop version of the site. I have changed my questions accordingly.