# .htaccess to redirect specific index file when particular url is visited

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have one website url `http://t8.example.info/home.html`
I want to redirect this url to `http://t8.example.info/index.php?id=802` when i open it in mobile version.
I dont want to redirect when it is open in desktop version. It should be open as it is in desktop version.

need a quick help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20106417/htaccess-mobile-redirect-for-specific-url

Comment: unfortunately, its not works for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at last i found one solution
i use below code in .htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /home.html$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://t8.example.info/index.php?id=802 [L,R=302]
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about htaccess but you can achieve it from javascript

```
var isMobile = /iPhone|iPad|iPod|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
if (isMobile) {
  window.location = "http://t8.example.info/index.php?id=802";
}
```